# Chart.js Skip Data

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js, linechart

Is there a way to only draw dots on the grid lines based on the unit and unit step size ?

The gridlines and labels are skipping right, but when I change the unit and/or unit step size, the dots are still drawing between the gridlines.

```
let chart =  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                time: {
                    unit: 'day',
                    stepSize: 3
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wsf23bgn/1/

-edit-

I found out that this function is called aggregate(avg) in Kendo UI Graphs